# Make models fields readonly in all admin pages

Tags: python, django, django-models

My project has multiple Models and custom admin pages for the models. All the Models inherit from a "BaseModel". For business functionality, we had to update our "Base model" to include 2 new fields. Given that all models inherit these 2 new fields, they are now showing up in admin pages as editable fields. As per business functionality, these two fields should be displayed as read-only fields

For making fields readonly we normally use readonly_fields = [read only..] in admin class. Is there a way to achieve this without touching all the admin classes?

Comment: You can make the two fields `editable=False`

Comment: ```editable=False ``` Makes the field hidden

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a base admin model class and use it on every admin model class. AFAIK, it will be the best solution you can have

```
from django.contrib import admin


class BaseModelAdmin:
    """
    The base model admin class
    """
    readonly_fields = ["field_1", "field_2"]


class FooModelAdmin(BaseModelAdmin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    """
    Inheriting the 'BaseModelAdmin' class here
    """
    ...


class BarModelAdmin(BaseModelAdmin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    """
       Inheriting the 'BaseModelAdmin' class here
    """

    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        """
        If you have "readonly_fields" that are specific to certain Model, override this method
        """
        readonly_fields = super().get_readonly_fields(request, obj=None) + ["bar_field_1", "bar_field_2"]
        return readonly_fields


admin.site.register(FooModel, FooModelAdmin)  # registering the model in Django admin
admin.site.register(BarModel, BarModelAdmin)  # registering the model in Django admin
```

Comment: Yep, this was one of the solutions that I thought of. But then some of the existing class already have readonly_fileds, which will effectively override the parent class readonly_fields.

Comment: If you have that situation, override the **`get_readonly_fields()`** method. Please do check my updated answer :)